# Why is my Vue local component not appearing in the page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue and messing around with examples in their guide. I am trying to [register a sub-component locally](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) inside a root vue component as described here. But it does not appear on my page. What am I missing ? app.components also returns undefined.

```js
console.log('Loading my script');

var componentX = {
    template: `<h3>Hello</h3>`
}


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-div',
    template: `<div>Vue is working</div>`,
    components: {
        'component-x': componentX
    }
})

console.log(app.components);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="vue-div">
        <component-x></component-x>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
    <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mounting vue on `<div id="vue-div">` **replaces** the content of `<div id="vue-div">` ... if you `template: '<div>Vue is working<component-x></component-x></div>',` in `new Vue` it will work

Comment: So will I always have to write my sub-components in the template for the parent component ? I thought I could write it directly in the HTML.

Comment: remove the `template` from `new Vue` ... then the existing HTML is used ... you can't do both :p

Comment: okay got it. Can you answer the question ?

Comment: Nah, I can't describe it well enough :p I just know you have one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, your main Vue has a template - this replaces any HTML inside the target element

So, you can either add the `component-x` inside the new Vue constructor template:

```js
console.log('Loading my script');

var componentX = {
  template: `<h3>Hello</h3>`
}


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-div',
  template: `<div>Vue is working<component-x></component-x></div>`,
  components: {
    'component-x': componentX
  }
})
console.log(app.$options.components);
```

```html
<div id="vue-div"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="./js/test.js"></script>
```

Or you can remove the template: from the new Vie constructor and the existing content of the target element will be used

```js
console.log('Loading my script');

var componentX = {
  template: `<h3>Hello</h3>`
}


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-div',
  components: {
    'component-x': componentX
  }
})
console.log(app.$options.components);
```

```html
<div id="vue-div">
  Vue is working
  <component-x></component-x>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
```

Comment: any idea why app.components still returns undefined ?

Comment: perhaps you want `app.$options.components`

Comment: Yeah I need to read more before I start experimenting :D